# Re-use of a regular expression capture group in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

The following python code *does* work but the regular expression 'search' is  evaluated twice:

```
# my_string varies, it gets the following strings = ['%10s', 'comma%11d', 'comma%-6.2f', '%-8s'] in a loop
output_string = '|'
re_compiled_pat_int = re.compile(r'comma%(\d+)d')
re_compiled_pat_fp  = re.compile(r'comma%-?(\d+)\.(\d+)f')
re_compiled_pat_str = re.compile(r'%(-?\d+)s')

if re_compiled_pat_int.search(my_string):
    output_string += f' %s{re_compiled_pat_int.search (my_string).group(1)}s |' # results in | %10s |"
elif re_compiled_pat_fp.search(fld_format):
    output_string += f' %-{re_compiled_pat_fp.search(my_string).group(1)}s |'
elif re_compiled_pat_str.search(my_string):
    output_string += f' %{re_compiled_pat_str.search(my_string).group(1)}s |'
# 'output_string' becomes: '| %10s | %-11s | %-6s | %-8s |'
```

As you can see, for each if/elif I need the capture group  string to be also plugged into the output string, but I see no way but to re-evaluate it in order to extract the captured group. As noted here, python 3.8'th Walrus operator (:=) can be used but I still have Python 3.6.

Is there a more elegant way to use the evaluated group just  once?

Comment: Just use `m = re_compiled_pat_int.search(my_string)` and then `if m:`... Although it will be done more elegantly in Python 3.8

Comment: As above comment. if you need to use the result of the regex more than once then store the result in a variable and then do all your stuff against the variable.

Comment: You have no other way to do that in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be done via assigning the `re.search` result to a variable and then checking if the variable is not `None`:

```
m = re_compiled_pat_int.search(my_string)
if m is not None:   # or 'if m:' will do, too
    # Do something
```

In Python 3.8, [there is an option](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) to get the match object in the if condition using a walrus operator `:=`:

```
if (match := re_compiled_pat_int.search(my_string)) is not None:
    # Do something with match
```

See [more info about the walrus operator introduction](https://hub.packtpub.com/python-3-8-available-walrus-operator-positional-only-parameters-vectorcall/):

> Python 3.8 has a new walrus operator := that assigns values to
>   variables as part of a larger expression. It is useful when matching
>   regular expressions where match objects are needed twice. It can also
>   be used with while-loops that compute a value to test loop termination
>   and then need that same value again in the body of the loop. It can
>   also be used in list comprehensions where a value computed in a
>   filtering condition is also needed in the expression body.
>
> The walrus operator was proposed in PEP 572 (Assignment Expressions)
>   by Chris Angelico, Tim Peters, and Guido van Rossum last year. Since
>   then it has been heavily discussed in the Python community with many
>   questioning whether it is a needed improvement. Others are excited as
>   the operator does make the code more readable.